# Mac is not sorting by filename correctly (Not a Group By or Arrange By issue)

Tags: macos, sorting

I've noticed a strange sorting issue on my Mac OS in Finder.   I have image files with the following format:

PROJ-202301-General-{random 5 char string}*0*{maker name}*{datetime stamp}*{title}.jpg

I have Group By set to "None".  I sort of filename and it does not properly sort.  See image below. Seems to not want to sort on the random 5 char string properly.  Thoughts?

[image: sorting problem]

Comment: MacOS uses the Unicode Collation Algorithm which has that unfortunate side effect of leading zeroes being ignored, sometimes when you'd think they shouldn't be. See  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381775/85275

Comment: Interesting, I’ve never heard of that. But then why is the file shown at the very bottom of the picture sorted at the bottom of the list? I think it should be at the top of the list, and I think something else is affecting this sorting.

Comment: @jimtut That one's last because the sorting algorithm parses "141b0" as starting with the number 141, which is greater than the 99 that "99f78" starts with.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I've changed the script that renames the files to use a numeric string starting with A and ending with Z (  A123456Z ).  that should solve the issue.  This was added so that when people uploaded images for a photo comp their images won't be sequential (which can bias a judge sometimes).  But the website I upload to sorts them correctly (0-9 a-f) and it creates confusion for everyone. LOL.  Thanks for the feedback.